# Edit DataGrid row redirect to another page with holding the data in the coresponding fields?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a Data Grid view with the following colums, in VB.Net

Student Name, Address , Phone etc. and edit hyperlinkfield as well.
When I click on the Edit link on a Row, it should redirect me to studentdetails page and carrying the row value to the corresponding controls like Nametext , addresstext, phonetext controls etc.

I am new to vb.net and datagridview. Can anyone let me know how this works?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Place code to open the new form/page in the hyperlinkfield's click event. To access the other information from the same row you can use

`DataGridViewName.CurrentRow.Cells(studentName).value`

or

```
DataGridViewName.Rows(e.rowIndex).Cells(studentName).value
```

Then you get these values for the current row and pass them to whatever method in launches your new page, or set as properties on the edit form.